# Programatic Binding to Custom button doesn't fire Execute Action

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this simple custom button

```
<Button 
    x:Class="MyResources.Recursos.Controles.Controls.InLineButtonControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyResources.Recursos.Controles.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" 
    x:Name="ThisInlineButton"
    d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource InLineButton}">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image 
                    x:Name="BtnImage"
                    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonImage}"
                    Source="{Binding ElementName=ThisInlineButton,Path=ImageSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
</Button>
```

And a collection of buttons that must be included in a StackPanel programatically, my image source is defined as DP of my custom button, but for the command I want to use the default CommandProperty of it.  The class that represents each button looks like this

```
public class ImageTool : BaseModelPrimario
{

    ...

    #region Comando
    private DelegateCommand _Command;
    /// <summary>
    /// Command: Comando
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand Command
    {
        get { return _Command; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Command, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And I added each button as this:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataContext is ImageToolsControlVM vm)
    {
        StackPanel st = StkToolBar;
        st.Children.Clear();
        foreach (ImageTool cmd in vm.Tools.OrderBy(o => o.Orden).ToList())
        {
            InLineButtonControl btn = new InLineButtonControl
            {
                ImageSource = cmd.Command.ImageSource,
                Command = cmd.Command
            };
            _ = st.Children.Add(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is something like this

[image]

As you can see the image assignation is working fine but the command doesn't fire the ExecuteEvent.

I tryed changing direct assignation to binding like this

```
_ = btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("Command"),
    Source = cmd,
});
```

But doesn't works.

Must I create another Command DP for my command?
How bind to the Default CommandProperty of my inherited button?

Comment: Does your `DelegateCommand` implement `ICommand`? Maybe you attach that class to your Question too.

Comment: Could be anything like you've missed to initialize the Command property. The code you showed is not sufficient to review your command logic. You should put a  breakpoint inside the execute handler and run the application in debug mode.

Comment: @dba Yes it implement's it.

Comment: @BionicCode Execute doesn't fire. DelegateCommand is my base ICommand implementation and it runs fine when binding / assignation succeeded at XAML code. But I'm going to recheck again.

Comment: are you sure, the button get's the right DataContext passed? (handle the Loaded event of your button in codebehind). Since you are using a Stackpanel, the children will inherit the Datacontext of the parent control  - so the whole Collection of buttons). Otherwise, than e.g. Datatemplated Listbox, where the items receive the Item as Datacontext

Comment: Try `btn.DataContext = cmd;` in your 'adding-loop' and use the Binding-Method

Comment: @dba Tks, I'm going to take a look into it. Finally I created a *DP* of *ICommand* type and bind it to my original buton's  Command.